# Is there an easy way to test alchol content after brewing wine?

Tags: wine, alcohol-content

I'm making blackberry wine, is there any cheap and easy way to find the alcohol content after brewing? (Ive lost my barometer reading from before)

Comment: You don't "brew" wine. You simply ferment it. Brewing is for beer. Plus I am voting to close. This question has been asked many times.